# Using getComponent() in swing to call a variable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Alright this may seem like a weird question but is there a way that after calling something like
 `jPanel3.getComponent(0).getName();`
 That I can use that value to make a call on a variable. Basically if it returns say jLabel1. That I can use that to call something on that label such as .setText("Hi"); Instead of having to type jLabel1.setText("hi"). Meaning can I use the returned value to directly call a function on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want something like this:

```
Component c=jPanel3.getComponent(0);
if (c instanceof JLabel)
    ((JLabel)c).setText("hi");
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks so much Jon, and thanks for the other suggestion Paulo

Answer (score 1):

The `name` property of Components (i.e. `getName()` and `setName()`) have no relation to the variable which you once used when creating it. You can do this, for example (but don't, as this is very confusing):

```
Component textField1 = new JLabel("text");
textField1.setName("comboBox1");
System.out.println(textField1.getName()); // comboBox1
```

There is no way to get back to your `textField1` name - the variable may not even exist anymore when you are calling the `getName()` method. You can even create (and use) components without ever using an explicit variable for them, like this:

```
panel.add(new JLabel("text"));
```

As written by Jon, you can cast the component to the real type, and don't need the name of the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that when there is a panel as component available which is having two fields like label & textfields(It can be textfield & texfield).

```
Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
            for (Component component : components) {
                if (component instanceof JPanel) {
                    JPanel subPanel = (JPanel) component;
                    JLabel label = (JLabel) subPanel.getComponent(0);
                    JTextField textField = (JTextField) subPanel.getComponent(1);
                }
            }
```